# Mixed Content Issue

Tags: asp.net, https, mixed-content

Currently I am working in software Development Company where we have an eLearning System.  Product has collection of sites and main page contain 3 iframes which loads different web sites. We are going to enable SSL on the site in order all sites. Currently we put this on hold since we experience Mixed Content Issues because of following reasons.

•   Some of the elements in the user’s data which refers http content. 
Ex: img, js etc
•   Some of the third party web sites which loads in our iframes. (Different content provider)

We thought of developing our own web proxy, but we do have concern about performance as well as expensiveness of this solution. Can anybody tell what are the available solutions for the Mixed Content Issues and available third party web proxy where we can buy?

Answer (score 0):

Apache has [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) built in.  It's free, and works nicely.  Nginx (also free and very good) has [proxy_pass](http://proxy_pass%20-%20Nginx).

Please don't write your own proxy.  There is no need to.

[Here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/396966) is someone who has done exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: User can put external js,css which can be locate anywhere in the internet. Does it cater this

Comment: You want the *user* to be able to put JS out on the internet, have you host it, and be able to serve it up as if it were your own?  This is a horribly dangerous thing to do.  You are setting up a wide open proxy effectively.  I'm sure It can do these things, but I think it would be as a forward proxy, not a reverse one.  If you *really* want to do this, please read this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy so that you understand some of the risks...  You will definitely be targeted as a host for some of the nastiest characters on the internet, and will incur significant legal liability.

Comment: We are not hosting those. User (proffesor) can put whatever he wants.